# how to execute a bash script in given directory

Tags: bash

I want to change all of the files with some extension (e.g. `.png`) to a different one (e.g. `.PNG`) but I have a problem becaase I don't know what to type to make the script execute in given direction. I want it to work in specific catalog.

My current code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

Ext1=$1
Ext2=$2
Path=$3

for file in *${1#*.}; do

  echo `ls "$3"`
  mv "$file" "${file%.$1}.$2"

done

  echo `ls "$3"`
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you dont know how to execute the script in the current directory? What shell are you using and what have you tried? If its a bash script. Then chmod +x script_name makes it executable then you can just ./script_name to execute it. This will then generate output showing success or detail of the errors you script has.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me as a function without (ugly) backticks and some error/syntax correction...

```
renall(){
Ext1=${1}
Ext2=${2}
[ ${#} -eq 3 ] && Path=${3} || Path=.

for file in $(ls "${Path}"/*."${Ext1}"); do
  printf "Original: %s\n" ${file}
  mv "${file}" "${file%.${Ext1}}.${Ext2}"
done

printf "Moved to: %s\n" $(ls "${Path}"/*."${Ext2}")
}
```

You only have to source it. Then it works path independent and of course it is executable. When above scriptname is renall.sh then...

```
 # . renall.sh 
 # touch test.png
 # renall png PNG
Original: ./test.png
Moved to: ./test.PNG
 # renall PNG png
Original: ./test.PNG
Moved to: ./test.png
 # renall png PNG .
Original: ./test.png
Moved to: ./test.PNG
 # renall PNG png .
Original: ./test.PNG
Moved to: ./test.png
```

...and: Yes, it works with more than only one file to rename

Comment: thank you that really helps out, but now I seem to have a problem when the directory isn`t given

Comment: Try the dot ( . ) for the current directory like: ```renall png PNG .```

Comment: I made a new version where the named variables be used and ```Path``` is checked. If ```Path``` is not present then current directory will be used.

Comment: What's the point of `ls`? Just `for file in "${Path}"/*."${Ext1}"`. `printf "Moved to: %s\n" "${Path}"/*."${Ext2}"`

Comment: Only for control. Using of ```renall png PNG &>/dev/null``` puts out nothing.

Comment: Thank you for all of the answers, I found what was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're doing this as a programming exercise, try `rename .png .PNG *.png` on some systems. I think there are two `rename` programs out there that do different things so verify with `man rename`.